# Unable to save data to plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, dataset, plist

Below is my method to save data:

```
self.doctorString = @"Doctor Bob";

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"doctorprofile.plist"];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.doctorString, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"DoctorName", nil]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:&error];

if(plistData){
    [plistDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Data saved successfully");
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);

}else{
    NSLog(@"Data not happily saved");
}
```

My plist structure as below:-

[image: PLIST STRUCTURE]

It returns `Data saved successfully` message but when I checked on the plist file, it is not saved there.

Comment: What is the return value of the call to `writeToFile:`?

Comment: @rmaddy the path to doctorprofile.plist

Comment: No. It's either `YES` or `NO`. Check the return value of `writeToFile:`.

Comment: @rmaddy how do I check that ? I was using NSLog. Sorry am new to ios programming.

Comment: You can Check  by this way

if([plistDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES]){
NSLog(@"Data Saved");
}else{
NSLog(@"Data Not Saved");
}

Comment: deleteddddddddd

Comment: @KKRocks What? The bundle has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: If you're including the plist with your application, you'll want to copy that file into the Documents directly when the app first starts up (if it hasn't already been copied there). Then, any read and write operations you want to do on the plist should be done from the copy in the Documents directory instead of the version in the app bundle.

Comment: @user1498840 which .plist file you have checked after your method calling . which means in document directory or which you have added in your project.

Answer (score 0):

As per my reading of the code given, it will only write the key for `DoctorName` with the value of `Doctor Bob`. There is no error in the code itself. You can check the return value of `writeToFile` method as per below.

`BOOL ret = [plistDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];`

if the return value is YES the data is written to .plist file.

Comment: the return value is 1 but when i checked on plist file, nothing changes.

Comment: I just ran the code and it works fine and saves the value in plist file correctly. You must have some other problem in your code, try to run only this code to check if it saves it or not.

Comment: will it override my plist data or it will append ?

Comment: It overrides the previous data.